# Reversing a list without (append)

Tags: performance, beginner, lisp, scheme, sicp

I would like to reverse a list using cdr, car and cons. Since lists in lisp are asymmetrical (can only insert at the beginning), I am interested on how one would write a procedure to do that without using (append). Please review my code.

```
(define (reverse l)
    (define (aux orig result)
        (if (null? orig) result
                (aux (cdr orig) (cons (car orig) result))))
    (aux l '()))
```

Is this good enough? Are there better or more efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you don't want to use `append`, this looks great to me. I'm not sure if I can even think of a different way to do it.

My only suggestion would be naming related. `l` is a terrible name for a variable - it's too close to `1`. `orig` is questionable, since it's not really the original list, it's the list you're currently "popping" (logically, not literally) off of - so you could simply rename both `l` *and* `orig` to something like `lst` or `xs` or `elems` or ....